# What Compiz addons/plugins are available?

Tags: compiz, plugins, add-on

How many Compiz Addons can I get and what do they do?  Can I get one that make it possiable for me to turn windows and tab then like in Haiku.

Comment: Open [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/)  and search for 'compiz'. You will find there all packets, addons and plugins related to CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can install many Compiz plugins with one command

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Then go to software center and install compiz config settings (cant remember the package name for apt)

This allows you to config them, open it in dash and choose the "effects tab"

You will see there are now many, many effects you can use, some of my favourites include

Wobbly Windows, cube desktop changer, some nice fire effects and in the animations tab you can chage the open/close/min etc for the windows, I like the dream effect.

I know you asked what is available but there is to many to list here as you will see and the best ones are very subjective.

Enjoy